# How to choose random words from a list and hide them with underscores in C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, random, replace, underscores

I'm doing a program that has to show a text and every time the user press enter the program has to choose random words from the words list and hide them with underscores.

```
My mom loves me because I am a good boy
```

Then, when you press enter you should see something like this:

```
My mom _____ me because _ am a good boy
```

If you press enter again more words are going to be hide. That way:

```
My mom _____ me because _ am _ good ___
```

If you keep pressing enter the program is going to hide more words until all the words are hide. When all the words have been hidden the program has to finish the execution. The purpose of this program is to help people memorize texts.

What I did was create a list of words:

```
List<string> wordList = new List<string> {"My","mom","loves","me","because","I","am","a","good","boy"}
```

I used the Random() method to choose a word randomly from the list above:

```
var random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(wordList.Count);
string randomWords = scripture[index];
```

Then I created a for loop to iterate through the list of words and I used Replace() to put underscores where the random choice used to be. Finally I show this replaced list to the user:

```
 foreach (string a in wordList) 
{
  string newList = a.Replace(randomWords, "_");
  Console.Write(newList);
  Console.Write(" ");
}
```

I got something like this:

```
My _ loves because I am a good boy
```

When I press enter It shows me the text again with another hide word but it doesn't maintain the changes (I mean the words that have been hidden), it just keep replacing words infinitely and the number of underscores are not equivalent to the number of letters of the hide words. Please help me.

Comment: Instead of replacing the words in the list, it'd probably be easier to store separately which word should be hidden. That way, when you render the list, you can simply just print a number of underscores equal to the word's length. When you pick a word to hide, if you pick a word that's already been hidden, draw another word at random.

Comment: `string.Replace` returns a new string based on the specified replacements. You'd have to replace the string in the list with the result but you can't using `foreach` because you mustn't modify sequence while enumerating it. Create a new list or use `for`.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with your `worldList` and then build a list of randomized indices from that list then it becomes a matter

```
List<string> wordList = ["My", "mom", "loves", "me", "because", "I", "am", "a", "good", "boy"];
List<int> randomized_indices = Enumerable.Range(0, wordList.Count).OrderBy(x => Random.Shared.Next()).ToList();
```

Then it's just a matter of incrementally taking more indices from `randomized_indices` and replacing those words with underscores.

So start with `int do_this_many = 0;` and call this is a loop:

```
    IEnumerable<string> output =
        wordList
            .Select((word, index) =>
                randomized_indices
                    .Take(do_this_many)
                    .Contains(index)
                        ? Regex.Replace(word, "[a-zA-Z]", "_")
                        : word);
```

At the end of the loop add to `do_this_many` until you've displayed the entire list as underscores.

Here's the full code:

```
List<string> wordList = ["My", "mom", "loves", "me", "because", "I", "am", "a", "good", "boy"];
List<int> randomized_indices = Enumerable.Range(0, wordList.Count).OrderBy(x => Random.Shared.Next()).ToList();

int do_this_many = 0;

while (true)
{
    IEnumerable<string> output =
        wordList
            .Select((word, index) =>
                randomized_indices
                    .Take(do_this_many)
                    .Contains(index)
                        ? Regex.Replace(word, "[a-zA-Z]", "_")
                        : word);
                        
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", output));
    
    if (wordList.Count == do_this_many)
        break;
        
    do_this_many += Random.Shared.Next(1, wordList.Count - do_this_many);
}
```

That outputs like this:

```
My mom loves me because I am a good boy
My mom _____ __ because I am _ ____ ___
My ___ _____ __ because I am _ ____ ___
My ___ _____ __ because I __ _ ____ ___
__ ___ _____ __ because _ __ _ ____ ___
__ ___ _____ __ _______ _ __ _ ____ ___
```

If I were trying to make it more useful I would do this:

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> wordList = ["My", "mom", "loves", "me", "because", "I", "am", "a", "good", "boy"];
    
    var xs = MakeMaskLines(wordList);
    
    foreach (var line in MakeMaskLines(wordList))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", line));
}

IEnumerable<List<string>> MakeMaskLines(List<string> words)
{
    List<int> randomized_indices = Enumerable.Range(0, words.Count).OrderBy(x => Random.Shared.Next()).ToList();

    int do_this_many = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        yield return
            words
                .Select((word, index) =>
                    randomized_indices
                        .Take(do_this_many)
                        .Contains(index)
                            ? Regex.Replace(word, "[a-zA-Z]", "_")
                            : word)
                .ToList();


        if (words.Count == do_this_many)
            yield break;

        do_this_many += Random.Shared.Next(1, words.Count - do_this_many);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm gonna try it. One more thing I want to know is: Do you guys know why VS Code underlines 'Regex' in red? I tried to use it before and it throws me error.

Comment: @Zandhox You need to fully qualify it with `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` or add a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of your source file.